# Is a single wire input/signal possible?

Tags: sensor

Is any kind of (human) input/signal possible using one wire?

Maybe a coil and button with a magnet?

Maybe measuring the capacitance of the wire somehow?

Comment: Input what? A button press? capacitive touch sensors exist...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Any kind of (human) input. Button, touch, movement, temperature change... etc.

Comment: When you say one wire, do you mean no other link? Lots of options are out there if the components have a common ground.

Comment: @Puffafish No, I mean precisely with "floating voltage", no common ground.

Comment: Yep, as shown by radio reception by portable radios in plastic cases

Comment: @TonyM That means basically a (powered) transmitter and an antenna + reciever?

Comment: Capacitive sensors will definitely tell you when someone's touching the wire. Or you could build a theremin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with a single-wire sensor input is the same as the problem with a single-wire electric “circuit”.

In order to put an electrical signal into a wire, you have to push electrons into (or pull them out of) the wire. In normal electric circuits, the electrons flow in loops, so that the *density* of electrons throughout the circuit does not change. If there isn't a loop, then pushing or pulling changes the density, and that means you immediately have [a huge electrostatic force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) opposing the change. You can do it but the voltages quickly become enormous, as they do with any significant electrostatic effect.

Considered as a circuit element, [this forms an extremely low-value capacitor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187139/capacitance-of-a-single-charged-plate). And like any capacitor, its characteristics depend on the dielectric and what's on the other side of it (i.e. air or skin and flesh); the technique of extracting information from this is called **[capacitive sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_sensing)** and it's probably what you want to use.

---

Another way to carry, or perspective on, a signal over a single wire is [Goubau line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goubau_line) or [single-wire transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_transmission_line). You could think of this as a little bit like using a high enough frequency to pass that tiny capacitor. However, it is an RF signal and as such it must be considered as a wave passing through the space around the wire as well as, or instead of, the wire itself — you cannot route the wire next to other wires or other conductive objects without affecting the signal.

Since we've brought up radio waves, I'll also note that a radio is *not,* despite popular understanding, an example of a device that transmits or receives information with a single wire. A radio antenna *always* has two parts which experience a voltage *difference* between them. (Those parts may be the visible antenna and the chassis of the device, or they may be the two ends of a single antenna conductor tapped off somewhere other than the ends.) That voltage difference in the antenna is directly created by the voltage difference in the electromagnetic wave in space — if you've misaimed your antenna so that there is no voltage difference (such as by having the wrong *polarization*), then you receive no signal.

Comment: If you would be so kind, could you expand on capacitive sensing?

Comment: @data Sorry, that's not something I've worked with, so I don't know where to start for practical purposes.

Comment: @data An internet search will yield a plethora of information and capsense circuits that you can build, but the basic gist is that a sensor (wire, copper pad, spoon, apple) is attached to the circuit - which generates a field around it. When that field is disturbed, the circuit senses the changes, and reacts accordingly. The reaction is determined by the circuit's configuration. There are also ICs that require minimal components to achieve the goal, but they are mostly small SMD chips. I've been playing with the TTP223-BA6 recently, and it's lots of fun.